# Can I retrieve my notes from my iCloud without the phone?

Tags: ios, icloud

Recently my phone broke and it doesn't turn on anymore, and I have been wanting to retrieve my notes on iCloud but only found that the ones that were backed up on the iCloud were some useless ones that I don't really need… so my question is: is there a way to retrieve all notes from my iCloud from my computer without the phone?

Answer (score 2):

All your iCloud notes are accessible from [iCloud.com/#notes2](https://www.icloud.com/#notes2). If the notes you're looking for are not listed here, they are not stored in iCloud.